# Book recommendations for protein structure refinement

Tags: biochemistry, computational-chemistry, reference-request

I’m an undergraduate Chemistry student and I’m currently writing my dissertation about semi-empirical methods, particularly PM7, applied to protein structure refinement from X-ray structure. Could you recommend me any book/article about it?

Comment: I think this is clearly defined enough to get a reasonably-scoped answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3536963/) about PM6/7 which might be useful.